# Compile mysqli with mysqlnd to use as dynamic extension?

Tags: php, mysqli, mysqlnd

Can I compile mysqli with mysqlnd to use as a dynamic extension? I would need to do this for linux from a windows machine (though I could use a linux distro if needed).

**WHY?**
Because my hosting provider is dumb. mysqlnd should be the default driver for PHP 5.4+, but they don't even use it for their PHP 7.0 version.
Contacting them was a waste of time, as they insisted mysqlnd was deprecated in favor of mysqli (which isn't how it works).

Comment: as indicated in the [installation documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd.install.php) mysqlnd is installed as default from 5.3 onward **on windows**. for unix *"The MySQL database extensions must be configured to use the MySQL Client Library. In order to use the MySQL Native Driver, PHP needs to be built specifying that the MySQL database extensions are compiled with MySQL Native Driver support."*

Comment: Dang. So if they compiled all of their PHP versions with libmysql  for linux there is no way to use an extension that makes use of mysqlnd...unless I install my own compiled version of php